# Angular Group validation of fieldsets

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, forms, validation

AngularJS validation works fine with `ng-required`, but I wanna see if all form elements inside my fieldset are valid.

```
<form>
    <fieldset>  
        <legend>
            Part one
            <img src="/correct.png" ng-show="part_one_valid">
        </legend>
        <input type="text" ng-required=1 ng-model="name" placeholder="name">
        <input type="text" ng-required=1 ng-model="foobar" placeholder="email">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Part two
            <img src="/correct.png" ng-show="part_two_valid">
        </legend>
        <input type="text" ng-required=1 ng-model="name" placeholder="name">
        <input type="text" ng-required=1 ng-model="foobar" placeholder="email">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

That's the structure of the HTML simplified. 
What I wanna do, is show the image when the input fields inside the fieldset are valid.

Answer (score 11):

Take advantage of `ng-form` directive, where multiple forms can be nested inside each other using it. I'd suggest you to use use `ng-form` directive to make `fieldset` to act like a form and give some specific `name` to it, to enable the form validation on your form fields you need to use `name` attribute on both form as well as on the elements of the form.

**Markup**

```
<form name="myForm">
    <fieldset ng-form="part_one">  
        <legend>
            Part one
            <img src="/correct.png" ng-show="part_one.$valid">
        </legend>
        <input type="text" name="name" ng-required=1 ng-model="name" placeholder="name">
        <input type="text" name="foobar" ng-required=1 ng-model="foobar" placeholder="email">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset ng-form="part_two">
        <legend>
            Part two
            <img src="/correct.png" ng-show="part_two.$valid">
        </legend>
        <input name="name" type="text" ng-required=1 ng-model="name" placeholder="name">
        <input name="foobar" type="text" ng-required=1 ng-model="foobar" placeholder="email">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `ng-form='formX'` directive on each fieldset (since you cannot put one form tag inside another). 
Then just use `<img src='myimg.jpg' ng-show='!!formX.$errors.required' />` inside each fieldset

You can create directive to encapsulate that.

```
  <form>
    <fieldset ng-form='form1'>  
        <legend>
            Part one
            <img src="/correct.png" ng-show="!!form1.$errors.required">
        </legend>
        <input type="text" ng-required=1 ng-model="name" placeholder="name">
        <input type="text" ng-required=1 ng-model="foobar" placeholder="email">
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset ng-form='form2'>
        <legend>
            Part two
            <img src="/correct.png" ng-show="!!form2.$errors.required">
        </legend>
        <input type="text" ng-required=1 ng-model="name" placeholder="name">
        <input type="text" ng-required=1 ng-model="foobar" placeholder="email">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```